# failed to log in jira from java

Tags: java, jira

I have developed an application which needs to be logged in Jira from a java class, but a have a problem.
This is my java code which helps me log in jira:

```
jira = new Jira("https://jira.atlassian.com/");
        jira.login(myUsername,"myPassword");
```

but it throws this exception:

> org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: java.lang.Exception: com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteAuthenticationException: Invalid username or password.

I'm sure that my username and password are correct.
Can you help me please?

Comment: I'm sure they aren't correct

Comment: i have logged in jira website in this username and this password and it work correctly!!!

Comment: in jira website, i log in through my email address,and it work correctly

Comment: I am not sure at all... that Objects and methods does not exists on latest JRJC

Comment: Is your passport `"myPassport"`, or is it stored in a variable called `myPassport`? :)

Comment: Can you please provide a direct link to the library you are using to connect? Or a maven dependency, doesn't matter

Comment: this problem is resolved,i try this with a different username and password.

Comment: this problem maybe due from my account

Comment: The reason why I asked you was that you have the name in a variable `myUserName`, but your passport as a String literal '"myPassport"`, so I was wondering that you might have there one pair of extra double-apostrophes by mistake :)

Comment: thank you for you precious help

Comment: Can we create Jira issues from a java code?